# Appbar with views smooth resize on scroll

Tags: java, android, android-coordinatorlayout, smoothing, appbar

I want to resize my appbar and its views in a smooth way when recyclerview is scrolled.

```
-----------------
|     Title     |
|_______  ______|
|       ||      |
|_______||______|
|               |
|               |
|               |
-----------------
```

should become

```
-----------------
|_______  ______|
|_______||______|
|               |
|               |
|               |
-----------------
```

I'm using a CoordinatorLayout so i tried to resize views height onNestedScroll with a custom Behavior class but it won't do it in a smooth way, what can I do?

EDIT: i've been asked some code to show, i actually have not written much code to handle the resize but here it is

```
@Override
public void onNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull AppBarLayout child, @NonNull View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, int type) {
    super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type);

    if (dyConsumed > 0) {
        child.findViewById(R.id.channelName).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        child.getLayoutParams().height -= dyConsumed;
    }
    if (dyConsumed < 0 && !target.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
        child.findViewById(R.id.channelName).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

the thing is that onNestedScroll gets called only at the end of the scroll, so the resize is done when scroll is finished, while i want it to resize in real time

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Android **CollapsingToolbarLayout** is a wrapper for **Toolbar** which implements a **collapsingAppBar**. It is designed to be used as a direct child of an **AppBarLayout**.
This type of layout is commonly seen in the Profile Screen of the Whatsapp Application.

This layout consists of:

**Collapsing Title:**
The title is larger when the layout is expanded. The text size becomes smaller as the layout is collapsed and scrolled off the screen.

**app:layout_scrollFlags:** The scroll flags of this layout is typically set to “scroll|exitUntilCollapsed”.

**app:collapsedTitleGravity:** Specifies the gravity of the title in the container when collapsed.

**app:contentScrim:** This requires specifying a drawable or color value of the CollapsingToolbarLayouts content when it has been scrolled sufficiently off-screen eg. ?attr/colorPrimary.

**app:scrimAnimationDuration:** Specifies the duration used for scrim visibility animations. This requires an integer value such as “100”.

for eg https://cdn.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/android-collapsing-toolbar-default-output.gif

Example Code: `

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expandedImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/photo"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />`
```

Ask any confusion in the comment, Hope this will help.